# Solve the differential equation very tough to solve!!

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Today a classmate of mine had given me and my teacher a differential equation I don't know from where but it became a headache for me and my teacher because we both were unable to solve it at some particular step.
Here is the differential equation:

$$x\, \frac{dy}{dx} + y \ln(x) = x\,e^x\,x^{(1/2) \ln x}.$$

When I and my teacher was solving we compared it by 
$dy/dx + Py =Q, $
but when it came to integrate $Q$ (I.F.) it would integrable by me. So please help me in this question. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I've taken a stab at typesetting your DE. Please confirm it's correct.

Comment: Thanks for editing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a $+/-$ mistake: if either '$+ y \,\text{ln}(x)$' is changed to '$- y \,\text{ln}(x)$' or $x^{\frac{1}{2}\,\text{ln}(x)}$ is changed to $x^{-\frac{1}{2}\,\text{ln}(x)}$, the resulting integral is explicitly solvable. As it stands, the integral, which is essentially $\int e^{x + \text{ln}(x)^2}\,\text{d}x$, is not solvable.

Comment: Oh that means give ODE is not solvable there might be mistake

Comment: Please make the appropriate changes and then tell the method to solve he might have given wrong I will suggest him those suggestions given by you guys .